# Regular expression without 00 as a substring

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to create a regular expression for the language:

$L=\{w \in \{0,1\}\mid w \text{ does not contain 00 as a substring}\}.$

I've tried various things, but I can't seem to get the correct regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's start by enumerating the building blocks of length 2.

```
S = { 01, 10, 11, 00 }
```

We can immediately remove `00`

```
S = { 01, 10, 11 }
```

Next, notice `10 + 01` will create a sequence of `00`. So, let's remove `01` (10 could also be removed.

```
S = { 10, 11 }
```

Our basic solution is `(10 + 11)*`

However, this does not account for Empty Set + 0 + 1. It also does not account for odd length strings.

Final Solution

```
(E + 0 + 1)(10 + 11)*
```

Comment: The (10 + 11)* assumes that 0s occur only in the second position out of every 2 characters. They could occur in the first position as well.

Comment: what is the wrong in this regular? `1*(01+1)*0*1*`

Comment: I mean:`1*(01+1)*01*

Comment: What about *110110*?

Comment: @greybeard, that's right. The RE requires all even length strings to start with 1. "01" would be the shortest string that is falsely not recognised.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

> $0?(10?)^*$

Accepts the empty string.

> $0(10?)^*|(1^+0?)^+$

Does not accept the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following should work:

1. $(1+01)^*(0+\epsilon)$
2. $(0+\epsilon)(1+10)^*$
3. $1^*(011^*)^*(0+\epsilon)$
4. $(0+\epsilon)(11^*0)^*1^*$

Comment: (Watch out for *markdown* to eat characters like asterisks, which it considers special. Consider using $L^AT_EX$.)

Comment: Does the asterisk in `10*` apply to just the `0`, or to `10`? Can you please give a reference?